# How do I start a kubernetes job from an image in a local file system?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-jobs

Seems like an obvious thing do. Very common in other similar systems.  But I'm not seeing how to do it in kubernetes. What am I missing?

Comment: your cluster should have access to your locally managed registry

Comment: You create a [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/deploy-app/deploy-intro/) and point it to your local image / cluster.

Comment: Not really, no.  These all seem to be taking the image from a local registry, not the local file system.  AFAICT, kubernetes simply can't do this.

Answer (score -1):

You can try running a local secure registry, creating a pod (using a `YAML` file) from a Docker image in a local registry:

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69371808/553663) link.

Comment: Again, that's from a local registry, not the local file system.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that by a *kubernetes job* you refer to an app you can simply do so by creating a deployment following [this tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/kube-deploy/).

Comment: That appears to only take images from a local registry.  I'm looking for a way to take them from the local file system.

Comment: @agapanthusblue as a general rule a container can't access the host's filesystem, but you can take advantage of one of the storage methods presented here: https://docs.docker.com/storage/.